# Android Download http files (and update next) for offline

Tags: android, caching, webview, offline

I am novice in Android development and I want to build an application that can play an entire website in a webview with no connexion and can be update when the Wifi is connected.
I have seen many solutions to do that and I decide to use this work:

https://github.com/pprados/android-webview-async-cache

I have no problems to stop connection when the app is on and I can continue with the cache but when I close the app and go back on (without connexion), it's not working.

May be you can help me to understand why?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally try my code with another website (like YouTube) and it's work better.
I think my problems come from the fact that the entire website is divided into one folder "assets" and in various branches that are different from the home page.

My Website also uses a lot of links to javascript, ajax and jquery files.

Edit 01/12/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy):

I'm not sure but I think the problem is related to the Template Engine (smarty).

If anyone has had the same caching problems as me, with this kind of server, thank you to tell me if you found a solution or how you solved the problem.